# Spring Data JPA query method for more than one criteria

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data

I want to add in my Repository interface a method for following SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM my_db.location where last_date is null ORDER BY act_date DESC
```

I've run this query in mysql workbench it's working as expected. I've created the following method name for JPA

```
findAllLastDateIsNullByOrderByActDateDesc() {}
```

But it's only doing the descending ordering but not by last date is Null. Please help me to find out the correct way of doing this.

Comment: Try this SELECT * FROM my_db.location WHERE last_date IS NULL ORDER BY act_date DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
findAllByLastDateIsNullOrderByActDateDesc();
```